# Calculate x,y coordinates factoring in a rotation

Tags: javascript, math

I'm working on a video editing design tool. I've recently added a rotation feature and my X,Y coords are now off.

Within a 1080x1080 artboard, I have an object that is let's say for example sake 690px by 891px. When this object is flush against the left side it's X value should be 0.

Now if I rotate it 30deg clockwise. The box will be transformed where the left edge is now below 0. If I drag it over I want to be able to calculate it so that when the left edge in it's rotated form is at 0 when it touches the left plane of the artboard.

*A screenshot demo of the app I'm working on*
[image]

I've tried other formulas but I am not 100% understanding them or even sure they apply to what I am trying to solve.

Summary: Looking to calculate the x,y coords of an object when its rotated. In the screenshot below that x coord should be 0.

The dimensions are in the screenshot. I'll list them out anyway.

x = 195
y = 117
w = 690
h = 891
rotation = 30
artboardW = 1080
artboardH = 1080

Based on those dimensions how do I make x become 0 with a 30 deg rotation inside a 1080 x 1080 box?

Cheers!

Comment: What you mean by `x,y coords of an object ` ? Some corner? Center?  Rotation occurs around some center - what is rotation center in your case?

Comment: The image is a good example. The object is an HTML div that could be anything, SVG, image, video, etc. They all have a width, height, and transform. The transform will keep track of it's x and y coordinates. Then when a rotation is applied it is added to the transform. `translate(179.198px, -100.802px) rotate(90deg)`

Comment: When it's 90 deg. Essentially when the bottom (in the 90deg) hits the left edge I should detect the X coordinate to be 0;

Comment: Look at the formula:  `X_new = Rot_center_X + (X_old - Rot_center_X) * Cos(Fi) - (Y_old - Rot_center_Y) * Sin(Fi)`.  You want to find angle Fi when X_new becomes 0?

Comment: Are Fi and Theta the same? Basically the degree? I failed math, am learning a lot though lol. I'll plug that in and if it normalizes the object on the 2D plane then I would say yes this is the formula. Let me check

Comment: Angle might be described by any letter/name. Degrees or radians - depends on you math library, most (and javascript Math) work with radians as arguments of trigonometric functions. I still don't sure in your primary goal. Find what?

Comment: When a box inside a box has rotated the edge of the inner box should be at 0 when touching the edge of the parent box.

Im trying to figure out the true x,y coords factoring in the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple trigonometry problem...

```
    const rads = (Math.PI * 2) / bars;

    const x = centerX + Math.cos(rads * i) * fooRadius
    const y = centerY + Math.sin(rads * i) * fooRadius
```

I've seen you applying that somewhere else:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-tereshkova-1pf0c?runonclick=1&file=/src/Visualizer.js:2473-2646

Something that I do not see in the description of your problem is the pivot point,
that is key to this problem, ye you got `rotation = 30` but from where?

If we rotate with a pivot point in one corner after rotation that corner will not change location...
All you need to do is calculate the distance to pivot before rotation and that is our radius.
Reuse equation, rinse and repeat for every rotation.

Maybe this image will better illustrate the role of the pivot:
[image]